# to get the three dimensional graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data in a text file like this.

```
a   b       kseq
613 42023   20
762 32557   20
323 63163   20
643 60877   20
422 32740   20
394 48891   20
744 105341  20
334 58036   20
303 27343   20
861 33608   20
```

Is it possible to create 3d graphs from this 2 dimensional data in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Not a particularly exciting graph, as one of the variables is a constant, but definitely yes.

Modules involved are `csv` (for input) and `matplotlib.pyplot` (or `pylab`) to actually do the plot.

Please have a look at [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html) for getting started.

Should you get in trouble, please get back to SO with *another* question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

a = [[613, 42023, 20], [762, 32557, 20], [323, 63163,20], [643, 60877, 20],
 [422, 32740, 20], [394,48891, 20], [744, 105341,20], [334, 58036,20],
 [303,27343,20], [861,33608,20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a', 'b', 'kseq']) # create dataframe not neccessary
X = df.a
Y = df.b
Z = df.kseq
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
xi = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100)
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), 100)
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='linear')    # create a  uniform spaced grid
xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)  # create pair of x, y
surf = ax.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi, rstride=5, cstride=3, linewidth=0, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, antialiased=False)   # 3d plot
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```